.Net 7 app - publish database change via webhook
Trying to create a quick proof-of-concept.  I would like to publish database inserts to subscribers...
Some important pieces of code are my controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WebhooksController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly WebhookService _webhookService;
    private readonly MesMsSqlProviderContext _context;
    private readonly IBackgroundJobClient _backgroundJobClient;

    public WebhooksController(WebhookService webhookService, MesMsSqlProviderContext context, IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient)
    {
        _backgroundJobClient = backgroundJobClient;
        _webhookService = webhookService;
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost("subscribe")]
    public IActionResult Subscribe(WebhookSubscription subscription)
    {
        _webhookService.AddSubscription(subscription);
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost("publish")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Publish([FromBody] object payload)
    {
        _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => SendWebhooks(payload));
        return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(Ok());
    }

    public async Task SendWebhooks(object payload)
    {
        var subscriptions = _webhookService.GetSubscriptions();

        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            await client.PostAsync(subscription.Url, content);
        }
    }
}

And my service which uses SqlDependency:
public class SqlDependencyService : ISqlDependencyService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly string _commandText = "SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[TransactionBase]";

    public SqlDependencyService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MesMsSqlProviderContext>();
            _connectionString = context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
        }
        RegisterDependency();
    }

    public event Action<object, SqlNotificationEventArgs> OnChange;

    public async void RegisterDependency()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(_commandText, connection))
            {
                SqlDependency.Start(_connectionString);
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += Dependency_OnChange;

                // NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
                await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        OnChange?.Invoke(sender, e);
        RegisterDependency();
    }
}

The next step is to handle the change event and call the Publish method on controller.  But do I just use an instance of a HttpClient to call the Publish endpoint?  This seems odd to me since the code is all in one project.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
